# Realizar consulta para sumar valores y agruparlos por mes en una fila por id (cliente)

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos

Estoy tratando de realizar una consulta para realizar un reporte, pero al hacerla no estoy seguro cual sera la mejor forma de construir el query, la idea es agrupar por cliente y mostrar en columnas el total facturado por mes ejemplo:

```
oficina  cliente  enero   febrero marzo   abril   ....    diciemb total
======== ======== ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= ======= =======
```

Lo que he construido hasta el momento es:

```
Select f.oficina as Oficina, cf.cliente as Cliente,
(SELECT sum (f.importe) FROM factura WHERE Id_cl = cf.Id_cl
and month(fecha) = 1) as enero,
(SELECT sum (f.importe) FROM factura WHERE Id_cl = cf.Id_cl 
and month(fecha) = 2) as Febrero,
(SELECT sum (f.importe) FROM factura WHERE Id_cl = cf.Id_cl 
and month(fecha) = 3) as marzo,
(SELECT sum (f.importe) FROM factura WHERE Id_cl = cf.Id_cl 
and month(fecha) = 4) as abril,
(SELECT sum (f.importe) FROM factura WHERE Id_clf = cf.Id_clf 
and month(fecha) = 5) as mayo,
(SELECT sum (f.importe) FROM factura WHERE Id_cl = cf.Id_cl 
and month(fecha) = 6) as junio,
(SELECT sum (f.importe) FROM factura WHERE Id_clf = cf.Id_clf 
and month(fecha) = 7) as julio,
(SELECT sum (f.importe) FROM factura WHERE Id_cl = cf.Id_cl 
and month(fecha) = 8) as marzo
From factura f
INNER JOIN Cliente cf on  f.Id_cl = cf.Id_cl
```

El resultado es lo esperado, pero no creo que sea la mejor solución para generar un query tan grande, quisiera saber como podría optimizar esta consulta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes encararlo de forma más sencilla con una suma condicional, lo cual además es más performante que las subconsultas a nivel de columna:

```
Select  f.oficina as Oficina, 
        cf.cliente as Cliente,
        sum(case when month(f.fecha) =  1 then f.importe else 0 end) as enero,
        sum(case when month(f.fecha) =  2 then f.importe else 0 end) as febrero,
        ... 
        sum(case when month(f.fecha) = 12 then f.importe else 0 end) as diciembre
    From factura f
    INNER JOIN Cliente cf 
        on f.Id_cl = cf.Id_cl
    GROUP BY f.oficina, 
             cf.cliente
```

Esta clausula: `sum(case when month(f.fecha) =  1 then f.importe else 0 end)` que debes reproducir para cada mes, realiza la suma únicamente si es el mes es el de la columna.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, funciono muy bien, solo le añadí un Group By para que los agrupe por cliente.

Comment: @Jozeslond, tienes toda la razón, se me escaparon los `group by`

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una consulta que devuelva los resultados de las facturas, eso sería una sola lectura de datos, luego envuelves esa consulta con otra donde hagas las agrupaciones, así:

```
Select f.oficina as Oficina, cf.cliente as Cliente,
(SELECT sum (f.importe) FROM Consulta WHERE Id_cl = cf.Id_cl
and month(fecha) = 1) as enero,
(SELECT sum (f.importe) FROM Consulta WHERE Id_cl = cf.Id_cl 
and month(fecha) = 2) as Febrero,
(SELECT sum (f.importe) FROM Consulta WHERE Id_cl = cf.Id_cl 
and month(fecha) = 3) as marzo,
(SELECT sum (f.importe) FROM Consulta WHERE Id_cl = cf.Id_cl 
and month(fecha) = 4) as abril,
(SELECT sum (f.importe) FROM Consulta WHERE Id_clf = cf.Id_clf 
and month(fecha) = 5) as mayo,
(SELECT sum (f.importe) FROM Consulta WHERE Id_cl = cf.Id_cl 
and month(fecha) = 6) as junio,
(SELECT sum (f.importe) FROM Consulta WHERE Id_clf = cf.Id_clf 
and month(fecha) = 7) as julio,
(SELECT sum (f.importe) FROM Consulta WHERE Id_cl = cf.Id_cl 
and month(fecha) = 8) as marzo
from 
(
select * From factura f
INNER JOIN Cliente cf on  f.Id_cl = cf.Id_cl
)as Consulta
```

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server tiene la instrucción (no estándar) [`pivot`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017), que permite *rotar* el resultado de las filas de una consulta en columnas.

En este caso, podemos hacer una consulta donde agrupamos por mes, y luego aplicar una operación pivote para convertir las filas en las 12 columnas de los meses, para cada cliente.

```
select *
  from (
select   Factura.id_Cl
       , month(Factura.Fecha) Mes
       , sum(Factura.Importe) Importe
  from Factura
 where year(Factura.fecha) = 2019
 group by Factura.id_cl, month(Factura.Fecha)
) T
pivot (
    sum(Importe)
    for mes in ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12])
) as pt
```

Va a devolverte un resultado como este:

```
id_cl 1       2       3       4       5       6       7       8       9       10      11      12
----- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- ------- -------
1     100.00  125.50  131.50  10.50   NULL    187.50  NULL    142.50  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
2     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    132.50  47.50   54.50   NULL    NULL    NULL    459.50  152.50

(2 rows affected)
```